# Store ID is in wrong format

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-store-apps, win-universal-app

Assuming the 12-digit store-id of a durable IAP is 999999999999, `license.AddOnLicenses` contains the key **999999999999/0010** instead of the expected **999999999999**.

Code:

```
StoreContext store = StoreContext.GetDefault();
StoreAppLicense license = await store.GetAppLicenseAsync();
```

This is contrary to [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.services.store.storeapplicense.addonlicenses) which say [emphasis added]:

> A map of key and value pairs, **where each key is the Store ID** of an
>   add-on SKU from the Microsoft Store catalog and each value is a
>   StoreLicense object that contains license info for the add-on.

Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong (or understanding the docs wrong)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> where each key is the Store ID of an add-on SKU

What you are getting is **SKU Store ID**. It is a 4-character alpha-numeric string that identifies the SKU. An example complete Store ID returned by this property is 9NBLGGH69M0B/000N. Please refer [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.services.store.storesku.storeid).

What you are looking for is **product Store ID**. It is a 12-character alpha-numeric string, such as 9NBLGGH69M0B. This Store ID is available in Partner Center, and it is returned by the StoreId property of the related StoreProduct object. Please refer [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.services.store.storeproduct.storeid#Windows_Services_Store_StoreProduct_StoreId).

So you need to check StoreProduct.StoreId property.

Comment: Thanks. That seems to be it. This is insane. Instead of using `license.AddOnLicenses.TryGetValue(storeId, out StoreLicense iapLicense);` we now have to iterate over the `AddOnLicenses` and test if they _begin_ with `storeId`...

Answer (score 1):

**Every app and add-on has an associated license** that indicates whether the user is entitled to use the app or add-on.Every product in the Store has at least one SKU, and each SKU has at least one availability.

Some publishers have the ability to define their own SKUs.For example, a large game publisher might release a game with one SKU that shows green blood in markets that don't allow red blood and a different SKU that shows red blood in all other markets.

> test if they begin with storeId

Yes, it begins with Store Id(this is also sometimes called a product Store ID)

The Store ID for a SKU has the format `<product Store ID>/xxxx`, where xxxx is a 4-character alpha-numeric string that identifies a SKU for the product. As the picture shown:

[image]

For more concepts about product Id and SKU, please refer to documents: [Products, SKUs, and availabilities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/monetize/in-app-purchases-and-trials#products-skus-and-availabilities) and [Store IDs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/monetize/in-app-purchases-and-trials#store-ids)